# How to indent a 2nd line of wrapping text

Tags: css

I have an icon and some text next to it. The text wraps and the 2nd line appears below the icon:
[image: problem]

I want the 2nd line to line up with the start of the text. How can I do this? Here is my current html:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:checkin" alternative-text="Utility image" size="x-small" class="icon-1"></lightning-icon>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>
```

and the css for .icon-1 is just this:

```
.icon-1 {
    --sds-c-icon-color-foreground-default: #009fda;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:flex`

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  border:3px solid black;
  background-color:orange;
}
.icon{
  background-color:cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon">A</div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare erat nulla, vitae fringilla lectus aliquet ut. Ut sapien lacus, pretium ut vulputate posuere, dictum sed sapien. Aenean tincidunt, quam et maximus sollicitudin, elit eros tincidunt elit, in lobortis arcu risus non turpis. Donec nec velit ullamcorper, tempus nisl non, molestie metus.
</div>
```